# definition of "the object of the exercise"

Tags: meaning, vocabulary, sentence-meaning

Staying late at the office to discuss shorter working hours rather defeats the **object of the exercise.**

Would anyone please in a more vivd or detailed way explain what the sentence means?

*What is more I am wondering what the bold part could mean?* Or, I think it is worth using a synonym for the bold part so that I could get it better.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Staying late at the office to discuss shorter working hours rather defeats the object of the exercise.

You can substitute the words **goal, aim, purpose, meaning** in the stead of **object**:

> Staying late at the office to discuss shorter working hours rather **defeats the purpose** of the exercise.

**Defeats the purpose** is a very common combination of words.

What is the meaning of the whole sentence? Suppose an employee has proposed to gather a meeting (this is **the exercise**) in the office to discuss what could be done to make the working hours shorter. This is **the purpose** of the exercise: to make working hours shorter.  But staying late at the office actually makes working hours longer.

So we have a contradiction: the proposed exercise **defeats its own purpose**.